# finding the number of positive integral solutions

Tags: permutations, combinations

> Find the number of positive integral solutions of $x+y+z=n$, $n$ belongs to set of natural numbers, $n\ge3$

How far I've got:

The number of positive integral solutions
= coefficient of $x^n$ in $(x+x^2+x^3+...)^3$
= coefficient of $x^{(n-3)}$ in $(1+x+x^2+...)^3$

After this step what do i do?

Comment: $p_{_3}(n)=\bigg\lfloor\dfrac{n(n+6)}{12}\bigg\rfloor+1=\bigg[\dfrac{(n+3)^2}{12}\bigg]$. See [partitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Restricted_partitions) for more [details](http://dlmf.nist.gov/26.9).

Comment: how is this linked to the steps i've done?